# After upgrade magento 2.1.0 to 2.2.1 product export not working

Tags: magento2.2

After upgrade magento 2.1.0 to 2.2.1 product export redirect to dashboard.

Click on System > Export
then choose entity type Product and then scroll and click on continue.
Its redirect to dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause of the issue: Usage of deprecated config setting.

You may be having config value in core_config_data table for modules output restrictions. This functionality was deprecated in 2.2.0 and the config menu system -> advanced -> advanced was removed.

However the logic for processing existing settings was preserved. It should be removed in future releases of Magent. This is an issue with Core Magento

Since those options are deprecated and can be safely deleted. Below are the steps for the same:

1) Remove deprecated "modules_disable_output" values from core_config_data table:

DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "advanced/modules_disable_output/%";

2) Clean config cache:

php bin/magento cache:clean config

Note: Please try this in your dev or staging environment before deploying to your production environment.